# Cannot read property '__isVuelidateAsyncVm' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

Here is the code I have [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-1sk5j?file=/src/layout.vue), What I have here is a form with validation and the "Calculate" button which is disabled until all fields will be valid. But for some reason, I'm getting the error  `Cannot read property '__isVuelidateAsyncVm' of undefined` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*First some comments, it's great that you have provided a sandbox, but your question itself should contain the relevant code to reproduce the issue. This question becomes useless if (when) the link dies.*

Doing some debugging to actually find which field is causing this error. By eliminating one field after one, I noticed that it is the gender field that is causing your issue. So looking closer at `inArray`, your custom validator, I noticed that you are not returning anything, which causes the validation to fail. Add `return` to your `inArray`:

```
const inArray = (value, vm) => {
  // add return!
  return vm.items.some(gender => value.indexOf(gender) !== -1);
};
```

PS, as a hint, try to do some debugging to narrow down the issue and you might have solved this yourself :)

Rest of relevant code for your issue:

```
<v-select
   v-model="user.gender.value"
   :items="user.gender.items"
   label="Gender"
   :solo="true"
   :error-messages="userGenderErrors"
   append-icon
></v-select>
```

Script:

```
validations: {
  user: {
    gender: {
      value: {
        required,
        inArray
      }
    },
  }
},
```

**[FIXED SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-uuqms)**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so thank you Bogdan for the question and AT82 for the answer, it really helped me :)

I want to add my situation, I had this code:

```
validations() {
  return {
    VaccineUpload: {
      vaccines: {
        $each: {
          isValidInput: (vaccine) => {
            const { brand, date } = vaccine
            return (!brand && !date) || (brand && date)
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

And the return statement `return (!brand && !date) || (brand && date)` would return `null` instead of a boolean, which was generating the same error. My solutions was to change the code to:

`return !!((!brand && !date) || (brand && date))`

So always ensure you are returning a boolean to have a successful usage of the validations.